# Django how to define default app for home URL?

Tags: python, django, url, view, default

I'm learning Django, and so far I always had to use URL's like

```
projectname/appname/viewname
```

but what if I don't want `appname` to appear in the URLs for the "default" app, how can I configure my urls so that

`projectname/viewname`

will load the view `viewname` from my default app?

**P.S.** : Of course my primary goal is to be able to use the URL `projectname/` to load the default view for the default app.

### Details

Currently my ProjectName/urls.py has this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root', settings.STATIC_ROOT}
  ),                                          
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^myapp1/', include('myapp1.urls', namespace='myapp1', app_name='myapp1')),
    url(r'^myapp2/', include('myapp2.urls', namespace='myapp2', app_name='myapp2')),    
)
```

so when I deploy my project to Heroku, and visit `myproject.heroku.com`, I get the error :

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://myproject.herokuapp.com/
Using the URLconf defined in MyProject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^static/(?P<path>.*)$
^admin/
^myapp1/
^myapp2/
```

I know this is supposed to be, but how do I fix (or hack) this to get `myproject.heroku.com` to work?

If not possible, how can I redirect the homepage to `myproject/myapp1/defaultview` ?
Thanks in advance !

my app's urls.py looks like this :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('myapp1.views',
    url(r'^view1/$', 'view1', name='view1'), # the default view
    url(r'^view2/(?P<oid>\d+)/(?P<pid>\d+)/$', 'view2', name='view2'),
)
```

### Edit

After trying @Wallace 's suggestion `url(r'^$', include('myapp1.urls', namespace='myapp1', app_name='myapp1')),` and hitting the homepage, I now get the error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in myproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^static/(?P<path>.*)$
^admin/
^$ ^view1/$ [name='view1']
^$ ^view2/(?P<oid>\d+)/(?P<pid>\d+)/$ [name='view2']
^myapp2/
```

Comment: how's your `myapp1`'s **urls.py** looks like?

Comment: have you tried `url(r'', include('myapp1.urls', ...)`?

Comment: @Anzel added to the question. But it should be irrelevant for this task, right?

Comment: @Anzel, your suggestion works !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tried changing your project `urls.py` with:

`url(r'', include('myapp1.urls', ...)`

This will include all urls from `myapp1.urls` where they all append to `/`.

The reason why `r'^$'` won't work is because the regex ends with `$` which means there can only be 1 x url `/`, and because your `app1.urls` only has 2 urls defined and without a `/` or `^$` equivalent, the url resolver will then fail.

But *be aware* of url clashes, if your project has a `^view1/$` url it will clash to your `app1`'s `view1` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Try not including your appname in the regular expression.

```
url(r'', include('myapp1.urls', namespace='myapp1', app_name='myapp1')),
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and pasted the result at the end of question.

Comment: Try Anzel's answer, I did not test mine b4 posting.

Comment: @Wallace, `^$` won't work as the regex means only 1 url i.e `/`. Changed it to `r''` will append all `app1.urls` to `/` and so it will work